# Unexpected Identifier for Onclick Javascript button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, error

I created a custom button for custom object to place in the related list. The custom object has two look-ups, one for case and one for account. This button, when clicked, should open in a new window to save a record of the custom object, with the default values for each look-up to populate automatically depending on the record where the button was clicked. It works for every record so far, except one case. It then throws the error: A problem with the Onclick Javascript for this button or link was encountered: Unexpected identifier.

I couldn't find any differences between records where it works and doesn't.

Code:

```
window.open('a2U/e?CF00N600000037HI4={!Account.Name}&CF00N600000037HI4_lkid={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&CF00N600000037HI5={!Case.CaseNumber}&CF00N600000037HI5_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JSENCODE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5), because your account name has an apostrophe (single quote), which causes the string to be malformed. It needs to be properly escaped for JavaScript to not parse it incorrectly.

```
window.open('a2U/e?CF00N600000037HI4={!JSENCODE(Account.Name)}&CF00N600000037HI4_lkid={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&CF00N600000037HI5={!Case.CaseNumber}&CF00N600000037HI5_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes');
```

Comment: That was the problem. The instance causing the error had an apostrophe in the account name. Thank you!